# Android: making layouts in the activity's fragment, if not using several fragments

Tags: java, android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I am making an activity that contains a `ListView` and a `Button`. Being new to Android I didn't notice that I was writing it in the fragment xml document.

I noticed that the java code generated when making an activity (`Activity.java`) pertains to the activity xml, not the fragment, as `getViewById()` returns null when I try to get my `ListView` or `Button`.

My question is, should I move the layout from the fragment xml to the activity xml, or is there a way to call the fragment from the `Activity.java` file?

I read up a bit on the use of fragments and saw that they are mainly used while having several tabs, or "mini-activities" (sorta) in the same window/activity. I will not be needing that functionality though. Should I still be making the layout in the fragment xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setcontentview(R.layout.activity_main)
```

to

```
setcontentview(R.layout.fragment_main)
```

and remove below code

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment()).commit();
    }
```

from onCreate method thats it. now fragment remove from your activity.. also remove activity_main.xml no need to this xml...

Comment: activity_main.xml not needed? Isn't the activity the container of the fragment, or something like that?

Comment: yes but here we remove fragment concept from our app. so no need to activity _main.xml and what ever in fragment_main you can access in onCreate method using findviewbyid.

Comment: also remove fragment class declared in ActivityMain class.

Comment: Isn't one of the reasons for the concept of fragments to avoid needing to reload/reinitialize the entire activity when for example rotating the device?

Comment: if you do not want to avid fragment concept then just start your code in onActivityCreated() method in fragment class.

Answer (score 0):

/*You can add fragment in activity in java like this:
Fragment manager is responsible to manage all fragments you will have.
MyFragment is class that extends Fragment  and myFragment is object of that class.
 ContainerId is optional*/

```
FragmentManager manager=getFragmentManager();
    MyFragment myFragment=new MyFragment();
    FragmentTransaction transaction=manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.container,myFragment,"Stringtag");
    transaction.commit();
```